# Pandas fillna with an incremented value

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I have a dataframe with a column of sequential but not adjacent numbers and missing values.

I'd like to use the `fillna` function to fill in the missing values with an incremented value from the previous non-missing row.

Here's a simplified table:

```
index  my_counter
0      1
1      2
2      NaN
3      3
4      NaN
5      NaN
6      8
```

I'd like to fill in `my_counter` as such:

```
index  my_counter
0      1
1      2
2      2.1
3      3
4      3.1
5      3.2
6      8
```

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: Hi @EricM, could you please show your code as well? What have you tried so far?

Comment: My attempt (which was successful) involved looping and comparing, which is not the panda-centric solution I was seeking. Wen's solution below works quite well. Just need to add that you need to set my_column equal to that line of code since the intention was to "replace" the NaN with the incremented values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IIUC `ffill` with `groupby` `cumcount`

```
df.my_counter.ffill()+df.groupby(df.my_counter.notnull().cumsum()).cumcount()/10
Out[92]: 
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    2.1
3    3.0
4    3.1
5    3.2
6    8.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: is there a way to fill the NANs with series of UUID?

Comment: df=df.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(uuid.uuid4().hex))