# how to simulate pandas dataframe data with increment datetime

Tags: python, pandas

In python3 and pandas:

assuming i have a dataframe:

```
datetime,id,value
2020-03-12,1,100
2020-03-13,1,105
2020-03-14,1,110
2020-03-12,2,100
2020-03-13,2,105
2020-03-14,2,110
```

I am trying to simulate these datasets with x extra historical days.

Let us say x=2 for now, and we wont add any new ID. Just existing IDs in the datasets. The value column can be incremental or random. Wonder how could I do it?

The first thing we have to is to extend the time:

```
df2=pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime('today'), periods=10, freq='1440min'))

df['datetime']=df['datetime'].append(df2)
```

then i got

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Wonder how could I do it?

Comment: `df2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime('today'), periods=10, freq='1440min'), columns=['datetime']); df.merge(df2, on=['datetime'], how='outer')`?

Comment: to remove the error, you can add `ignore_index=True` as parameter of `append`, but it won't work as you want. But, you want to add `2020-03-15` and `2020-03-16` for each id, right?

Comment: Yes @Ben.T would like to add 2020-03-15 and 2020-03-16 for each id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way could be to `set_index` the datetime and id columns, then `reindex` with all the dates you want generated through `date_range` using [`pd.MultiIndex.from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and finally `reset_index` to put them back as columns like:

```
#ensure datetime is good format
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

#set parameter for extra days
x=2
df_re = df.set_index(['id', 'datetime'])\
          .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['id'].unique(), 
                                               pd.date_range(df['datetime'].min(), 
                                                             df['datetime'].max() + pd.Timedelta(days=x))], 
                                              names=['id', 'datetime']),
                   fill_value=120)\
          .reset_index()

print (df_re)
   id   datetime  value
0   1 2020-03-12    100
1   1 2020-03-13    105
2   1 2020-03-14    110
3   1 2020-03-15    120
4   1 2020-03-16    120
5   2 2020-03-12    100
6   2 2020-03-13    105
7   2 2020-03-14    110
8   2 2020-03-15    120
9   2 2020-03-16    120
```

Comment: Thank you! It works in my test case. But the real data actually returns ```Length of names must match number of levels in MultiIndex.```. Trying to figure out what happened

Comment: @Chubaka it seems that the parameter `names` in `MultiIndex.from_product` which is a list should be same length as the list containing the data like in this example `[df['id'].unique(), ...]`

Comment: oh yeah. I think the problem is the real dataset i need more than 'id' column to have unique results. I can either create a primary key, or I used ```df[['a','b',c']].values.ravel()``` which gives me the error. Since df[['a','b',c']] is a dataframe, the unique doesn't work in the case. Any thoughts? Thanks. @Ben.T

Comment: @Chubaka I would go to get a unique key per unique triple, otherwise try `df.set_index('datetime').groupby(['a','b','c'])['value'].apply(lambda x: x.reindex(pd.date_range(df['datetime'].min(), 
                                                             df['datetime'].max() + pd.Timedelta(days=2)), fill_value=120)).reset_index()` plus maybe some cosmetics to get the exact output

Comment: Hi @ben.T, I am trying to make the fill_value dynamic . like every day interval, the fill_value=120+y where y is an integer.  Wonder . any ideas of doing it?  Thanks

Comment: @Chubaka are you using the method with `groupby` like in the comment?

Comment: @Chubaka in the meantime, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52416574/pandas-fillna-with-an-incremented-value) can help even if it would not be efficient to implement it in this case I think

Comment: i actually think about updating the value columns by rows after generating the dataframe using your method. ``` for i in df['count'].index:
     df.at[i, 'count'] = 100+i*2 ```

Comment: @Chubaka I think if you don't fill_value in the `reindex`, maybe you can consider using something like `df['value'].isna().cumsum()` like this you have incremental value for each nan, but if it is not working for you, a new question may be easier to explain the problem :)